# Represent a set of functions and their typing rules

Tags: types, ocaml, typing, static-typing

I would like to represent a set of functions and their typing rules, and am thinking of the data structure... For instance,

```
For function "PLUS":
PLUS-integer: Integer -> Integer -> Integer, with priority high
PLUS-boolean: Boolean -> Boolean -> Integer, with priority high
...

For function "Unary Minus":
UM-0: Integer -> Integer, with priority high
UM-1: Date -> Date, with priority high
...

For function "Unary Minus":
UM-error: Date -> Error, with priority low
...
```

Some comments: The names of the functions and the rules are always unique; One function (e.g. PLUS) has always a fixed number of arguments and can have several typing rules related to it; A typing rule has one name (e.g. PLUS-integer), one premise, one conclusion and one priority. There may have 2 typing rules which share same premise, but give different conclusion, in this case it is the priority which makes the difference.

Later, I would need to define functions like:

```
add_rule: add a rule to a function
get_rules: get all the rules from a function
get_first_rule: get the most priority rule from a function and a premise
get_conclusions: get all the conclusions that a function can give
get_errors: get all the rules whose conclusion is an error
get_function: get the function from a typing rule
set_priority: set a priority for a rule
...
```

For this purpose, I don't know if there is a conventional way to define these types... at the moment, I imagine one way as follows:

```
type func =
    { name: string;
      ... }

type rule =
    { name: string;
      premise: Type.t list;
      conclusion: Type.t;
      priority: Priority.t
      ... }

type rules = rule list
```

Several questions:

1) is it a good idea to define `rules` as a list of `rule`, in comparison with array...

2) regarding the relationship between `func` and `rules`, there are several options: make `rules` as a record field of `func`; make `func` as a record field of `rule`; make a hash table of `func` and `rules`; make a map from `func` to `rules`. I don't really know which way is better...

Another aspect I need to consider is the initiation of this database, there are a lot to enter, so I hope the types I choose will make the initiation easy to enter and look straight-forward...

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

1 - the use of array or list, or something else, depends on how you intend to access the underlying data.

If you need random indexed access to rules, and the dataset is not changing much use an `array`. If the dataset is regularly rebuilt, and you access the elements sequentially, use a `list`. If you need to index the elements by something else than a contiguous range of integers, use an `assoc list`, a `map` or a `hashtable`

2 - same as above, it ultimately depends on the access patterns. Choose what seems the most convenient in your algorithms, and don't be afraid of refactoring your code if it happens to be the wrong choice after a while.

By the way, the `rules` and `func` type could be interdependant if needed, as for instance:

```
type func = {
    rules : rule list;
   (* ... *)
}
and rule = {
    funcs : func list;
   (* ... *)
};;
```